# Boilerplate project creation error

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, msbuild, boilerplate

I have downloaded the boilerplate project available here 
[Boilerplate](http://rehansaeed.com/asp-net-mvc-boilerplate/)

I have made sure that VS 2015 is up to date.

When trying to create a project (asp.net core MVC 6 (rc2) Boilerplate (also RC2))I get the error: The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\V14.0\Dotnet\Microsoft.DotNet.Props" was not found.  Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correect and that the file exists on Disk.

I've checked the path and this isn't there, question is, what is it? and where can I get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MVC 6 ASP.NET Core boilerplate RC2 as of May requires a set of tools that are supposed to be installed on to visual studio. These Tools are the Dotnet that is missing.

You can get them at here: https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#windows