# aspnetboilerplate template project creation build errors

Tags: boilerplate, aspnetboilerplate

I have created project from aspnetboilerplate templates [ASP.NET MVC 5.x, Multipage application with ef](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Templates).

I have unzipped the downloaded file
I have started Visual Studio as an administrator 
aspnetboilerplate site says we can use Visual Studio 2013 or later and
My Visual studio version is:
Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2015
Version 14.0.25431.01 Update 3
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.7.02046

When I try to open and build the project, the project has build errors which I have tried to resolve by from [Boilerplate project creation error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37697356/boilerplate-project-creation-error) but still its unable to resolve.

Build errors details are:

1. error CS0012: The type 'Object' is defined in an assembly that is
   not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard,
   Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.
2. error CS0006: Metadata file 'D:\AAA\Projects\SourceCode\Practices\MVC\HelloWorld\3.1.3\src\HelloWorld.Application\bin\Debug\HelloWorld.Application.dll' could not be found
3. error CS0006: Metadata file 'D:\AAA\Projects\SourceCode\Practices\MVC\HelloWorld\3.1.3\src\HelloWorld.Core\bin\Debug\HelloWorld.Core.dll' could not be found
4. error CS0006: Metadata file 'D:\AAA\Projects\SourceCode\Practices\MVC\HelloWorld\3.1.3\src\HelloWorld.EntityFramework\bin\Debug\HelloWorld.EntityFramework.dll' could not be found
5. error CS0006: Metadata file 'D:\AAA\Projects\SourceCode\Practices\MVC\HelloWorld\3.1.3\src\HelloWorld.WebApi\bin\Debug\HelloWorld.WebApi.dll' could not be found

I have tried all options searching for solution still its not resolving.
Any suggestions/help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> aspnetboilerplate site says we can use Visual Studio 2013 or later

Unfortunately, that is an [outdated instruction](https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/issues/2757).

> The type 'Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'.

ABP v3.0.0 is based on .NET Standard 2.0.

- This concerns you regardless if you are on MVC 5.x, .NET Framework 4.x or .NET Core 2.x.
- You should use VS2017 15.3.3+.

Using VS2017 15.3.3+, the projects will build, resolving errors 2 to 5.